# Find Max value of a column using cassandra hector in java.

Tags: cassandra, max

I am using UTF8Type comparator and have to find the max value of a column using hector cassandra in Java.

For eg:

I have in my cassandra database a column named Page Count and need the max page count.

Answer (score 0):

To do this sort of thing you'll either have to build your own index to manage it, or you'll have to use a map reduce job in Hadoop.  Cassandra doesn't support these kinds of aggregate ops.